# Combinations of Chebyshev polynomials and sin functions

Tags: trigonometry, chebyshev-polynomials

By chance, I see this formula

$\int_0^1 T_{2n+1}(x)\sin(ax) { dx \over \sqrt{1-x^2}}=(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}J_{2n+1}(a)$  but what is the closed form if we have

$\int_0^1 T_{2n}(x)\sin(ax) { dx \over \sqrt{1-x^2}}=?$

Here $T_n$ is Chebyshev polynomials of first kind and $J_n$ is Bessel function of first kind

Comment: I hope that [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hTLZY.png) will prove slightly enlightening.